# Conditional regex in PHP doesn't seem to work

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, preg-match, pcre

Performing a [regular expression match in PHP using the preg suite](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pcre.php), I understand that you can represent a conditional  statement right within the regex.

I could hardly find any documentation online so I turned to [Jeffrey E.F. Friedl's Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info).

The way I see it, something like `/(?(?<=NUM:)\d+|\w+)/` should match a digit when it is preceded by `NUM:` otherwise it should match a word.

But for some weird reason it always returns true and the match data doesn't make sense to me either. Can someone explain to me what's going on?

What I want to do is this:

```
preg_replace('/creat(?:e|ing)/i', 'make', $input)
but only when '/creat(?:e|ing)/i' is not surrounded by quotes.
```

in action, the input-output sequence I need is:

1. **input:** create a white shirt.

**output:** make a white shirt.

2. **input:** "create a white shirt."

**output:** "create a white shirt"

3. **input:** hello create some good code.

**output:** hello make some good code.

4. **input:** "hello" "make some" good "code."

**output:** "hello" "make some" good "code."

Thank you everybody!

**Edit**: I want to do something like: if there is an opening quote, make sure it has a closing pair before matching the keyword `create` in this case. Hope that makes sense and is possible.

Comment: So, what is the regex you used? `creat(?:e|ing)` only? But it matches `create` anywhere.

Comment: I couldn't even start as the if-else gave me unexpected results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need any conditional constructs to skip what is inside quotes. There are two ways.

Use an alternative branch matching a quoted substring and use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` verbs:

```
 preg_replace('/"[^"]*"(*SKIP)(*F)|creat(?:e|ing)/i', 'make', $input)
```

**Pattern details:**

- `"[^"]*"` - matches `"`, then 0+ characters other than `"` and then a `"`
- `(*SKIP)(*F)` - make the regex engine discard the currently matched text and proceed from the current index
- `|` - or...
- `creat(?:e|ing)` - match `create` or `creating`.

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/oV0eT2/1)

Another way is mere using capturing and using `preg_replace_callback` where you can check if a group was matched (and base the replacement logic appropriately):

```
 preg_replace_callback('/("[^"]*")|creat(?:e|ing)/i', function($m) {
     return !empty($m[1]) ? $m[1] : 'make';
 }, $input)
```

See the [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/vtx09m)

**Pattern details**:

- `("[^"]*")` - Group 1 (can be later referenced with `$1` from the replacement pattern) - a double quoted string
- `|` - or
- `creat(?:e|ing)` - match `create` or `creating`.

Note that `"[^"]*"` is a sample regex, if you need to match C strings with escaped sequences, you should use at least `"[^"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^"\\\\]*)*"` (in the code).

Comment: Wiktor, both of those expressions give me the same result. The 'create', both inside and outside quotes is replaced by 'make' as opposed to the desired output where 'create' is replaced only outside the quotes.

Comment: Did you check the demo? `We create it, "they create that"` -> `We make it, "they create that"`

Comment: I did. I copied both the code and the input directly from there and ran it on my localhost. It replaced both the 'create' words.
I'm taking the input through a textarea and outputting it on a browser too, hope that doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Are you sure you have `"`? Not `&quot;` or any other *literal* "entities"? Check if you have `htmlentities` before. `htmlentities` cannot be used before running the regex.

Comment: This was exactly what was happening, wrote the code long back. 
Just added htmlspecialchars_decode($input) and worked like a charm.

The second example makes sense and is pretty clever, did you come up with it yourself?

The first one though looks pretty alien, can you tell me how it works?

Comment: I will add explanation after lunch, ok? :) The main point is that `(*SKIP)(*F)` just omits the match and goes on searching for other alternatives.

Comment: Sure man, thanks a ton! I read an entire book on regular expressions never came across this. Fun fact, it's 6pm here.. Strange place, the world :)